# How to make a button link to another part of the same page and how to put a video from yt into my webpage

Tags: html, css, video

i am creating a website for the first time and need some help. Ive got 2 main issues. the 1st one is i want it so that when someone clicks on the 'basic info' button it links directly to that part of the page rather than to another page as all my information will be on that one page. Also i want to add a video on my webpage but i want the video to be their so users can just click the video and it starts up on my page rather than re-directing them to another page. (below is my html and css).

also if anyone has any visual tips on how to improve my webpage please feel free to drop a comment and help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
        <html>
        <head> 
        <title>Muhammed's Webpage</title> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Homepage.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" href="Homepage.js"> </script> 

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700

        |Arya:400,700|Nunito:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        </head>

        <body> 
        <div id="page">

        <div id="navigation"> 
        <ul> 
        <li><a href="BasicInfo"> Basic Information</a></li> 
        <li><a href="CV"> CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="Portfolio"> Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Report"> Report</a></li> 
        </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="intro"> 
        <h1> Muhammed Hussain </h1> 

        <h2 id="tagline"> I am a Computer Science student </h2>
        </div> 

        <div class="text" id="Basic Information"> 
        <h3 class="headers"> <u>Basic Information</u> </h3> 
        <p>In this section i will have some information about myself. <br> 
        For my finished website i'd like to make it responsive, so that it alters and readjusts 
        well to different screen sizes. I'd also like to include a gallery that uses javascript as
        i haven't used any javascript on this site yet. <br> 
        <br> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.

        </p>
        </div> 

        <div class="text" id="CV"> 
        <h3 class="headers"> <u>CV</u> </h3>
        <p> 
        Here i will have my twitter, instagram and facebook feed <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
        dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
        fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet
        a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
        Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="text" id="Portfolio">
        <h3 class="headers"> <u>Portfolio</u> </h3> 
        <p>
        Here i will showcase some of my current projects and completed projects. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat 
        massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In
        enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede
        mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. 
        </p>
        </div>


        <div class="text" id="Report">
        <h3 class="headers"> <u>Report</u> </h3> 
        <p>
        Here i will showcase some of my current projects and completed projects. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat 
        massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In
        enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede
        mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. 
        </p>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        </body>
        </html>


#page {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 85%; 
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 45px;
}

#intro { 
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 300px; 
    background-image: url("GoldsmithsPic.jpg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom right;
    /*background-color: #5c5c5c; */
    font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
}   
h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    padding-top: 40px; 
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 5em;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-top: 40px; 
    margin: 0;
}

#tagline {
    font-size:1.5em; 
    padding-top: 0px; 
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}
#title {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #434343;
}
#navigation {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right:0;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 85%;
    margin-left: 7%;
    opacity: 0.8;

}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top; 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #5c5c5c;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    color: white; 
}
.headers {
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.text {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
}
p {
    text-indent: 3%; 
    max-width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}
h3 {
    max-width: 95%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem 1:
give the div containing the 'basic info' an id,

then the link that should direct to that point should be like this:

```
<a href="#YOUR_SET_ID" />
```

using your code i did this:

```
        <li><a href="#BasicInfo"> Basic Information</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#CV"> CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio"> Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#Report"> Report</a></li>
```

or you can do it with jQuery
add this in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(
                    function () {
                        $("#LINK_ID").click(
                            function () {
                                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#DIV_ID").offset().top }, 2000, "easeInOutCirc");
                            }
                        );
            </script>
```

problem 2:
    you can get the embed code for the video from youtube under the share options, and paste it in the section of your html file you want to put the video

Comment: @mo.h is the video a youtube video?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reponse. I just tried what you said about adding an id but it only works correctly for one button which is 'portfolio'. for the other buttons it either doesnt work at all or links to somewhere else but the code is the same for all of them.

Comment: Also yes the video i want to import into my webpage is on youtube

Comment: @mo.h do you you have any repeated id's?

Comment: What do you mean repeated id's? also i have provided the code above (again thank you very much for your help)

Comment: Only portfolio worked for me. Can you send me what changes you made in your next comment then please and then ill just copy and paste it into my own code.

Comment: i updated the answer, is that what you have already? if you aim is to get the target div to the very top of the page, then you would need javascript something like the second answer, this just bring the div into view

Comment: I just copied and pasted that into my code and it made no difference, again only the portfolio button correctly works. the CV does too but it doesnt link to the correct place.

Comment: strange...works as expected for me, where does the CV link to?

Comment: As you can see in the code i provided above i just have a paragraph called CV, which is the same as portfolio. which is why i dont understand why my code isnt working. Also for the code embedding, will that need to be done in javascript?

Comment: no it wouldn't be in javascript, its an iframe, just copy and paste it in a div. have you tried my updated answer? the jquery part

Comment: Oh right, i havent tried it yet mate, will try it later on in the morning as i am about to go sleep now, will let you know how it goes when i try it. Again thank you fo much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If giving it an ID and linking to that ID doesn't work, look into doing it with Javascript or JQuery

Something like this maybe

```
element = document.getElementById("divFirst")
alignWithTop = true;
element.scrollIntoView(alignWithTop);
```

There is lots of content about this on the web, now that you know what your looking for

Oh an it looks so much better !

[Starting point for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. Also do you know how i can put a video from youtube on my webpage so that when they press it it starts up on my webpage?